# How to use a variable for a property name when using underscore.js findWhere function?

Tags: underscore.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set a property dynamically in underscore.js while using the _.findWhere function.

Here's the documentation for the function:

> ```
> findWhere_.findWhere(list, properties)
> ```
>
> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of
>   the key-value      pairs listed in properties.
>
> If no match is found, or if list is empty, undefined will be returned.
>
> ```
> _.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, {newsroom: "The New York Times"});
> => {year: 1918, newsroom: "The New York Times",
> reason: "For its public service in publishing in full so many official reports,
> documents and speeches by European statesmen relating to the progress and
> conduct of the war."}
> ```

Modeling the example in the docs, I want to set the property to search for dynamically:

```
 var publicServicePulitzers = [
    {"newsroom":"The New York Times", "year":2013 },
    {"newsroom":"The Los Angeles Times", "year":2012 }
 ];

var myprop = 'newsroom';
_.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, { myprop : "The New York Times"});
```

The result is undefined.

I also tried:

```
_.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, {eval(myprop): "The New York Times"});
```

The error message is SyntaxError: missing : after property id

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just figured it out.  The second parameter to findWhere is an object. So create the object first and pass that to the function:

```
var myprop = 'newsroom';
var value = 'The New York Times';
var search_obj = {};
search_obj[myprop] = value;

var result =  _.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers,search_obj);
```

Works!

Comment: Right but keep in mind that `findWhere` is really just a `find` call in disguise so building the `search_obj` for a single value doesn't do that much for you (or maybe it does depending on your tastes :).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `findWhere` for this, but a more generic [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find):

```
_.find(publicServicePulitzers, function(prize) {
    return price[myprop] == "The New York Times";
});
```

If you really need to use `findWhere`, have a look at [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key).